# How to detect half scroll of Listview builder / screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a pageviewbuilder from API. Now my goal is , when user in middle of the screen, I want to detect that and call the API again.
Right now I can only detect when user hit the bottom of the screen.

part of my code

```
 _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (((_scrollController.position.pixels)) ==
          (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)) {
        if (dataMap['has_more'] == true) {
          _pageNumber++;
          BottomLoader.of(context).during(jobMapGenerator(_pageNumber));
        }
      }
    });
```

I was trying to achieve the goal by doing this,

```
if ((_scrollController.position.pixels * 2) >
      (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)) {
    x++;
    print(x);
  }
```

but,It seems a fool's idea to generate a infinite loop!

The original concept of my work is from [HERE!](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)
And Some Reason, I just want to use scroll controller, not the NotificationListener!

Comment: Is that a `PageView` or `ListView`?

Comment: @iDecode ListView, sorry for my mistake , and Thanks a Lot  <3

Answer (score 2):

You can try this logic:

```dart
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
bool _loaded = false;
  
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    if (!_loaded && _scrollController.offset > _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent / 2) {
      _loaded = true;

      // Load your stuff here. Once done, you can again set _loaded to false
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is not working for me, don't know where the problem is!!
when ever I exceed the half area, it continuously  print the number until it's reached to bottom. 
my implementation of your code is -->  if (!_loaded &&
          _scrollController.offset >
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent / 2) {
        _loaded = true;
        x++;
        print(x.toString() + '-------------* *');
        setState(() {
          _loaded = false;
        });
      }